# How to handle fetch post request in PageModel in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have an Index.cshtml.cs file with PageModel code like:

```
namespace DemoApp.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
         public void OnPost() {}
         public void OnGet() {}
         public IActionResult OnPost([FromBody] JObject requestData)
         {
             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Request data = " + requestData);
             return Content("Registration successful");
         }
    }
}
```

And, I want to handle a Fetch Post request like this

```
fetch("/Index", {
    method: "POST",
    body: jsondata,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }
})
.then(response => response.text()) 
.then(data => {
    alert(data);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error("Error:", error);
});
```

How can I do it? Should the URL for POST request be different, or the handling method is not correct?

Comment: Is this code not working in some way?

Comment: See following : https://www.codecademy.com/learn/asp-net-i/modules/asp-net-page-models/cheatsheet

Comment: This is not the complete code. The javascript is working. But I am not getting any output in debug, so it means that the OnPost function is not getting hit.

Comment: @jdweng, I think PageModel cannot handle such Post request with json body, correct?

Comment: @Substantial-Code0: In your browser's development tools, on the Network tab, when the AJAX request is made, what is the server's response?  Also, why are there empty `OnPost` and `OnGet` methods?  Have you checked if one of those is being invoked instead?

Comment: @David Its giving 400 bad request. I just checked, OnGet is being executed. They are not empty methods, I just haven't put the code here, its very long and used for different function.

Comment: Wrong.  The body is IActionResult and must be valid.  The client serializes the JSON and then the server deserializes the body.  Add a break point and see if you get to the code.  You may be getting an exception

Comment: Correction, the OnGet is executed just when loading the page. When I click on the button that should submit Post, nothing is invoked. Where should I get the exception? In the browser?

Comment: In the fetch method, I am using 'Index' endpoint, is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice:Razor Pages are automatically protected from XSRF/CSRF,that's the reason why you always get the 400 response without getting into the endpoint when you debug

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-8.0) related

Add the code in your page:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

modify js codes:

```
    var payload = {
    name: "John", time: "2pm"
};
fetch("/", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    headers: {
        'RequestVerificationToken': document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[0].value,
        'Accept':"*/*",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})
```

Also,.net core  serialize/deserialize with `System.Text.Json` instead of `NewtonSoft.Json` since 3.x version

Don't bind the data with JObject,create a class for binding

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public string? Time { get; set; }
}
```

It works well on myside now:

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks. Then I had to create a model class similarly, and it worked.